# How to find an unsorted set of rows in a group by result only inside that particular group?

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

For exapmle :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNkYN.png)

Suppose table name is AMAN which is having more than 20 columns and more than 20000 rows

Now after this query:

```
SELECT id, line_no, date
FROM AMAN
where id in (select id from AMAN group by id);
```

Result:

[image]

We can see the groups with id 10000 and 20000 are having dates sorted.

I only need the **id** once when the dates corresponding to that are not sorted with respect to the line_no.

In this case I need **30000** as the desired output as the dates are in **unsorted order** with respect to the **line_no**.

Can anyone help me frame a similar query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the specific database so I'll provide a generic solution for it. The example runs in PostgreSQL.

You can use the `LAG()` window function to peek at a value in a previous row according to your desired sorting order.

For example:

```
select distinct id
from (
  select *,
    case when lag(d) over(partition by id order by line_no) > d 
      then 1 
      else 0 
    end as unsorted
  from aman
) x
where unsorted = 1
```

Result (see [running example at DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fv564vD58Q9kSbYPVwEG9F/0)):

```
id
-----
30000
```

SQL Script Data Set:

```
create table aman (id int, line_no int, d date);

insert into aman (id, line_no, d) values
  (10000, 1, date '2019-05-13'),
  (10000, 2, date '2020-05-13'),
  (10000, 3, date '2021-05-13'),
  (20000, 1, date '2015-06-14'),
  (20000, 2, date '2017-06-15'),
  (30000, 1, date '2024-05-13'),
  (30000, 2, date '2020-05-13'),
  (30000, 3, date '2022-05-13');
```

**EDIT FOR ORACLE**

The query works in Oracle with a slight modification, as shown below:

```
select distinct id
from (
  select aman.*,
    case when lag(d) over(partition by id order by line_no) > d 
      then 1 
      else 0 
    end as unsorted
  from aman
) x
where unsorted = 1
```

See [running example in Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b737c8b167665d11979000a5cdaae704).

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me . I am getting an error while running this query. Well in the beginning the records are not grouped , the first query I wrote is grouping them . Now after grouping I need to find the unsorted.  . . Can you give me a query which will do the entire thing in one go , basically ocmbining both the queries

Comment: @AmanSingh I just tried in PostgreSQL and works well. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fv564vD58Q9kSbYPVwEG9F/0

Comment: @AmanSingh If you are using Oracle database, please tag your question accordingly. And... the answer should work in Oracle as well.

Comment: Hi it is working fine in oracle database . But if there are more columns along with the existing ones then again it stops working and gives extra ids